# Using Python code in Java on App Engine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

Can I use Python code in Java on App Engine? What I mean is I am using Java to develop my App Engine cloud, but I need to include some Python code in it. How might I do that?

**Why?**

I need to [Generate Dynamic Content using Jinja2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/generating-dynamic-content-templates). There is no equivalent in Java. So I was hoping to be able to just do it in Python and include it in my Java code.

Comment: did you try JSP or GSP?

Comment: No I have never used JSP but I will look into it. With Jinja2 I get a String back and I can do whatever I want with it, such as saving the String to my data store and then serve my html from my datastore (sort of like a deep memcache) can I do the same with JSP?

Comment: I didn't try, but I'm sure it's possible. For strings there're better alternatives, such as StringTemplate and Apache Velocity, and actually many others

Answer (score 1):

No you can't run Python code if you are using Java, or vise versa, since App Engine is running in a sandbox and you are not allowed to run anything else other than Java in your case.